# C++ why can you initialize an empty string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This is a "how does it work" question. Based on my understanding, you have to initialize a non-dynamic array with a constant number of elements (int intarr[5]) or your array will write over blocks of memory that might be allocated for something else.

So why is it that you can initialize a string array (string strArray[]) without any elements?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s[] = {"hi", "there"};

cout << s[0] << s[1];
cin >> s[10]; //why is this ok?
cout << s[10];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... `string strArray[];` is not correct either

Comment: Please update your question to show small self-contained program containing a declaration that illustrates what you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, i could have asked the question better.Edited.

Comment: The thing is, this is definitely **not ok**

Comment: Oh so adding on to the array is not ok? I was informed that it was. (Which is why im so confused as to why it would not cause an issue)

Comment: You can't add to an array. It is fixed size. You can add to high-level containers, such as `std::list`.

Comment: You are trying to reach unallocated memory which is undefined behavior (and it's pretty bad :-P) I suggest you take some reads (even here on *SO*) about it so you'll understand it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a feature C++ (and C) allows you to declare an array without specifying the number of elements if you specify an initializer for it. The compiler will infer the number of elements that's needed.

So for

```
   int intarr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
```

The compiler will see that the array need to have room for 5 ints, and this is will be exactly the same as if you stated:

```
int intarr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

A string array is just the same;

```
 string s[] = {"hi", "there"};
```

is the same as if you wrote

```
 string s[2] = {"hi", "there"};
```

Your code has a serious bug though;

```
string s[] = {"hi", "there"};

cout << s[0] << s[1];
cin >> s[10]; //why is this ok?
```

`cin >> s[10];` is absolutely NOT ok. The array `s` has only 2 elements, and even if the compiler does not generate an error, you cannot use `s[10]`
Doing so results in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - so it could appear to work, or it could crash, or it could do anything.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was just misinformed. This really clears it up.

Comment: I would also mention that you need to specify all dimensions (in multidimensional arrays), _except_ for the first one, which compiler can deduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string strArray[]` in 2 ways

```
string strArray[] = {"apple","banana"};
```

or

```
void function(string strArray[]) {
    ...
}
```

In the first case, the size of the array is automatically determined by the number of initializers (2). In the second case, the size of the array is not needed because it is a formal argument.

Other than that, you must declare a size to the array. It doesn't matter if it is based on `string` or `int`.

If you are writing to `s[10]` in your example but only have 2 elements, you are writing to unallocated memory and the program behavior is undefined. It may not crash, but later on something bad will happen.

Comment: `void function(string strArray[]);` is completely equivalent to `void function(string* strArray);`. That is, it's not an array at all.

Comment: @MarkLakata in a parameter list, they really are exactly the same.

Comment: @jrok and nos - I stand corrected and learned something. There is a difference if you have a *multidimensional* array though, but for one dimension, there no difference.